# card.io IOS SDK won't scan silver cards

Tags: ios, card.io

I am working with the card.io IOS SDK but have had trouble with it scanning silver cards such as AMEX Platinum and others.  However, it works fine when trying to scan other color cards including ones that the numbers are not all that easily read.  Just silver seems to be causing an issue... anybody having the same problem?  Is this a limitation of the tech?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially silver is just gray and that becomes a contrast problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some cards are much more difficult to read than others, and it comes down to contrast and lighting. A good rule of thumb is that if it's difficult for you to read the card, the SDK will almost certainly have problems. But if it seems like it should be read, it's helpful to get an image of the card (obviously after blacking out the number) reported as an issue in the [Android](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues) or [iOS](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues) repo.